# How to draw colored circle with stroke in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, geometry, stroke

I found that I can do it using Pixmap:

```
void drawCircle(int x, int y, int radius)
```

Draws a circle outline with the center at x,y and a radius using the current color and ***stroke*** width.

The problem that their isn't a function that can set stroke width.

Is their any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to draw one before, with a bigger radius.
The stroke width would be the difference between radius2 and radius1.